# Modificar datos de un tabledlayout

Tags: android-studio

he aquí nuevamente molestando, les comento, después de eliminar una fila y de actualizar los números de la fila, por ejemplo poseo 6 filas y elimino la 3 ¿, por ende alñ actualizar las filas, esat queda así la queda como 3, la cinco como 4 y la 6 como 5... todo este proceso lo hace bien, si el problema esta en que quiero realizar actualizarlatabla, de esta manera:

```
private void actualizartabla(List<Presupuesto2> updatedDataList) {
    int rowCount = tbldatos.getChildCount();
    List<Presupuesto2> updatedDataListTemp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) tbldatos.getChildAt(i);
        String fila = ((TextView) row.getChildAt(0)).getText().toString();
        int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(((TextView) row.getChildAt(1)).getText().toString());
        String repuestos = ((TextView) row.getChildAt(2)).getText().toString();
        int valor = Integer.parseInt(((TextView) row.getChildAt(3)).getText().toString());
        String patente = m.getText().toString();
        // Obtener el ID asociado a la fila utilizando el mapa idMap
        int id = idMap.get(Integer.parseInt(row.getTag().toString()));
        // Resto del código para agregar los datos al objeto Presupuesto2 y a updatedDataList...
        Presupuesto2 updatedItem = new Presupuesto2();
        updatedItem.setID(id);
        updatedItem.setFilas(fila);
        updatedItem.setCantidad(cantidad);
        updatedItem.setRepuesto(repuestos);
        updatedItem.setValor(valor);
        updatedItem.setPatente(patente);
        updatedDataListTemp.add(updatedItem);
    }
    updatedDataList.clear();
    updatedDataList.addAll(updatedDataListTemp);
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (Presupuesto2 item : updatedDataList) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("ID", item.getID());
            jsonObject.put("N_Filas", item.getFilas());
            jsonObject.put("Cant_Repuestos", item.getCantidad());
            jsonObject.put("Repuestos", item.getRepuesto());
            jsonObject.put("Valor_Repuestos", item.getValor());
            jsonObject.put("Patente_Vehiculo", item.getPatente());
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // Realiza la solicitud POST al servidor enviando jsonData.toString()
    String url = "http://192.168.1.89/gestion/editar_presupuesto2-1.php";
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    for (Presupuesto2 item : updatedDataList) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("ID", item.getID());
            int filasValue = Integer.parseInt(item.getFilas());
            jsonObject.put("N_Filas", filasValue);
            jsonObject.put("Cant_Repuestos", item.getCantidad());
            jsonObject.put("Repuestos", item.getRepuesto());
            jsonObject.put("Valor_Repuestos", item.getValor());
            jsonObject.put("Patente_Vehiculo", item.getPatente());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final String jsonBody = jsonObject.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Datos actualizados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        cmdsuma.setEnabled(true);
                        cmdsuma.requestFocus();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Maneja el error de la solicitud
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error al actualizar los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                return jsonBody.getBytes();
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

a su vez les comento que el problema es que no modifica los datos, pongo un breakpoint desde el string URL, y no se cae en ninguna parte, lee bien los datos, que al entrar al ciclo form los lee y posteriormente entra al resquest de volley y viendo con el debugger me trae muy bien los datos, pero al terminar de frealizar el poroceso y me dirijo a la tabla en mysql y veo que no estan modificados los datos, ya que las filas quedan de esta manera 1,2,4,5,6, y como mencione anteriormente el actualizarfilas funciona ya que queda con 1,2,3,4 y 5:
Por otro lado, les muestro el arreglo json que poseo para tal proceso, es que cuando entre en el ciclo for y encuentre este debe entrar a modificar, es decir que lea todos los datos de la tabledlayout.

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
require("conexion1.php");
$conexion = retornarConexion();
$updatedDataList = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
// Obtener el índice numérico de la clave (por ejemplo, obtener 0 de "N_Filas0")
$index = filter_var($key, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// Obtener el nombre de la clave sin el índice numérico (por ejemplo, "N_Filas")
$fieldName = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $key);

// Crear o actualizar el arreglo asociativo correspondiente al índice
if (!isset($updatedDataList[$index])) {
    $updatedDataList[$index] = array();
}
$updatedDataList[$index][$fieldName] = $value;
}
// Realizar la actualización de los datos en la base de datos
foreach ($updatedDataList as $index => $data) {
$ID = $data['ID'];
$Filas = $data['N_Filas'] ?? null;
$Cantidad = $data['Cant_Repuestos'] ?? null;
$Repuestos = $data['Repuestos'] ?? null;
$Valor = $data['Valor_Repuestos'] ?? null;
$Patente = $data['Patente_Vehiculo'] ?? null;

if ($ID !== null && $Filas !== null && $Cantidad !== null && $Repuestos !== null && $Valor !== null && $Patente !== null) {
    // Construir y ejecutar la consulta de actualización
    $Filas = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $Filas);
    $Cantidad = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $Cantidad);
    $Repuestos = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $Repuestos);
    $Valor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $Valor);
    $Patente = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $Patente);
    $consulta = "UPDATE presupuesto2 SET N_Filas = '".$Filas."', Cant_Repuestos = '".$Cantidad."', Repuestos = '".$Repuestos."', 
    Valor_Repuestos = '".$Valor."', Patente_Vehiculo = '".$Patente."' WHERE ID = '".$ID."'";

    mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die ("Problemas al modificar".mysqli_error($conexion));
} else {
    // Imprimir un mensaje de error si alguna variable no tiene valor válido
    echo "Error: Datos de actualización inválidos para el ID: " . $ID . "<br>";
}
}
// Devolver una respuesta JSON
$response = array('message' => 'Datos actualizados');
echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

ojala que me puedan ayudar, ya que estoy muchos días en estos y nada de nada, y lo más raro que no cae la app, lo otro que inserta, modifica, elimina y lee bien todo de la base de datos, si este es solo el problema que quiero actualizar los datos en la tabledlayout, desde ya muchas gracias